# How to detect if a Google Play purchase is made from a test account or a regular account

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

I'm building an app where I have to detect if a purchase is a test purchase (made from a test account) or a real purchase from a real user. Note that the app is already live, and the SKU's I'm using are the same as the ones in production.

Google can detect if a purchase is a test, because it shows a message ("This is a test order, yo will not be charged"), but I'm looking for a way to detect that programmatically.

Comment: have you do something??

Comment: I've read here: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#testing-purchases that the orderId field should be null for test purchases, but that is not the case. Also I could not find any pattern that suggest that a purchase is a test from the data received from Google Play

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't need to be in real-time, you should be able to rectify it day(s) later by programmatically pulling down the sales reports with `gsutil`, and then parsing the CSVs for any orders where the title is prefixed with "Test: ".

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870?p=financial_export&rd=1#export

> **Download reports from Google Cloud Storage**
>
> Monthly reports are available from Google Cloud Storage. Reports
>   are generated daily and accumulated in monthly CSV files. They are
>   stored in a private Google Cloud Storage bucket for your Google Play
>   Developer account.
>
> You can access reports using Google Cloud Storage on your browser or
>   programmatically using gsutil. You can also use other tools to
>   programmatically access your Cloud Storage bucket.
>
> **Tip**: If you want to import your reports from
>   Google Cloud Storage into BigQuery, you need to convert the CSV files from
>   `UTF-16` to `UTF-8`.
>
> Your Google Cloud Storage bucket ID is listed near the bottom of
>   your **Reports** pages.
>
> Your bucket ID begins with `pubsite_prod_rev` (example:
>   `pubsite_prod_rev_01234567890987654321`).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm looking for a real-time solution, but thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The orderID is empty for test purchases.

Maybe there was a bug in the past for now that seems to do the trick.

Comment: I just got an order id for test purchase. I agree, it used to be empty.

Comment: same here. this definitely used to be empty, and now it's not. this is a huge problem because you need to be able to ignore test purchases when tracking your revenue.